# Android Get Uri path to file from Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api, android-file

I have this code to upload a file to my app, and when the file is opened with a file manager, or dropbox, or anything else, the returned path is correct and I can access it, I am only having problems with Google Drive, it returns some path starting with "exposed_content" and I can't "decode" it any way, I have searched and didn't found a way, anyone have any idea?

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if ((data != null) && (data.getData() != null)) {
                final Uri filePath;
                if (data.getDataString().startsWith("content")) {
                    filePath = getRealPathFromURI(getApplicationContext(), data.getData());
                } else {
                    filePath = data.getData();
                }
                // TODO bug with google drive
                if (filePath.getLastPathSegment() != null) {
                    tvSelectedFile.setText("File selected: " + filePath.getLastPathSegment());

                } else {
                    tvSelectedFile.setText("File can not be accessed, please try another way");
                }

            }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the attached code... from onActivity result you will get content uri ...pass this uri to the given method...

```
public static String getGDriveDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                           String[] selectionArgs) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_display_name";
    final String[] projection = {
        column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
            return null;    

}
```

Comment: what should I pass as selection and selectionArgs? I tried passing a null value, but I only get the file name, not a path to the file.

Comment: I would also like to know about what @jcesarmobile asked. It is not clear from the answer.

Comment: Yes i tested this code. It only gives the file name